# Probably "apply"-function-related

Tags: r

I am creating a d dimensional hypercube representing [0,1]^d through the use of the following code, which was kindly suggested by another user on this forum.

```
## generation of the d-dimensional hypercube
cube <- do.call(expand.grid,replicate(d, seq_len(mesh)/mesh, simplify=FALSE))
```

Let's say I have a function, say

```
 foo <- function(u) prod(u)
```

that I would want to apply to every point of the hybercube created above. Is there a nice way to avoid using a loop through the d rows to do so? I tried using various apply functions, but that was unsuccessful.

Thanks.

Comment: This makes no sense. Each point in the hypercube is of length 1 is it not? So what is `u` - a slice through this hypercube I suspect. How about a small, reproducible example the illustrates your problem?

Comment: No @Gavin, each point ("vertex" to be exact) of the hypercube is a point in R^d, i.e., a coordinates vector of length `d`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, a function for giving you the coordinates of the vertices:

```
hypercube <- function(d, coord = c(0, 1))
    do.call(expand.grid, replicate(d, coord, simplify = FALSE))
```

For example, using `d = 3`:

```
cube <- hypercube(d = 3)
cube
#   Var1 Var2 Var3
# 1    0    0    0
# 2    1    0    0
# 3    0    1    0
# 4    1    1    0
# 5    0    0    1
# 6    1    0    1
# 7    0    1    1
# 8    1    1    1
```

Then, to run your `foo` function on every vertex of the hypercube, use `apply`:

```
apply(cube, 1, foo)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That just optimized the running time of my code by a tremendous factor. Cheers